# Merging two dataframes with different variables and Id

Tags: r, merge

I have a database in 3 different dataframes: A, B, C.

A:
Patient id (unique)
Age: number
Sex: (0/1)

B:
Patient id (same patient more than once)
Treatment (1,2,3,4,5,6)

C:
Patient id (same patient more than once)
Diagnosis (1,2,3,4,5,6)

how can I merge them into one?

```
"1"<-subset (B, treatment== "1")
"1"<- table("1"$Id)

"1"<- dataframe("1")

list<-(1,2,3,4,5,6)
library(tidyverse)
treatment<-list %>% 
   reduce(full_join, by="Id")

treatment[is.na(treatment)] <- 0
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)
list(A, B, C) %>% reduce(left_join, by = "ID")
```

As an aside - FYI R won't let you store a data frame (or any variable) as a number at the beginning. Change 1 <- into df1 <-